Small electric motor doesn't work with high DC voltage?
I have a small electric motor (from a trimmer). I see this behaviour:

when I apply 2.5 VDC (from 2 AA batteries) to the motor, it works smoothly.
when I apply 4.2 VDC (from an adapter) to the motor, it barely spins or stops completely.

I am new to electric. I thought when I apply a higher voltage, the motor should run faster.
Please explain why that is? There are no other circuits, just the motor and the voltage sources

I measured the output voltage from this adapter by a digital multimeter and it shows 4.2 VDC


What are the specifications for your adapter? Add this information to the question, not in a comment. A photo of the label would probably be helpful.

@GodJihyo I just added

When connected to the wall wart, try to start the motor manually. Does it run now? (You need to remember the correct direction.)

If you measure the voltage with the motor connected, you'll probably find it has collapsed to a very low voltage.
Motors draw quite a bit of current before they get going (maybe 10x what they do under normal operation), and if your power supply cannot output the required current long enough for the RPM to increase enough they may never get going. Switching power supplies with current limiting often have to be massively overrated to work well with a motor load. You definitely have a switching supply (as evidenced by the wide input voltage range). The current doesn't just limit, it quits if the current is too high, waits for a while, and then retries. If the current is too high at every attempt it will never start up.
A linear adapter would likely work just fine. In this case, the adapter is poorly suited for the load. You might be able to convince it to get going with a huge capacitor across the output (allow the capacitor to charge before attaching the motor - try maybe 10,000uF or more- but many such supplies will also quit before they can charge the capacitor, for the same reasons) or by spinning the shaft with your fingers.

I added 20 mF capacitor to the adapter, the motor now can run but only without the razors attached to the motor (razors attached means the motor carrying load). Do I have to increase the capacity of the capacitor to get the motor run with razors attached?


I thought when I apply a higher voltage, the motor should run faster.

It would be if your adapter was a perfect voltage source. However, there are no such things in nature. An ideal voltage source can produce any current, but the real one is only the maximum (on your adapter there should be information about it). If a real voltage source is overloaded, it will begin to output a lower voltage. Thus, your adapter overloaded the motor and began to give a lower voltage value (and possibly went into protection).

exactly, I measured the output voltage of the adapter when the motor could not be running, it show 0.1 V

Your adapter is rated at 3 V / 1000 mA, and you measured it at 4.2 V which means you probably measured it with no load. Those adapters will typically put out more than the rated voltage with no load, and drop to close to the rating when fully loaded.
I'm guessing the batteries are rechargeable as standard AA cells are 1.5 V so you would get 3 V for two, while rechargeables may be 1.2 V NiCad which would give close to the 2.5 V you report. Either that or they're just run down.
The motor looks like a typical "hobby motor", they're just an armature and some fixed magnets so will work with a pretty wide range of voltages as long as it's not so much that the windings overheat. And yes, they should run faster with higher voltage. 1000 mA should be enough to run it.
So what could be causing the results you're seeing? Well, you would have to measure the voltage across the motor with the batteries and then with the supply and compare. Your adapter may not be supplying the current it says it can. Another thing that could be affecting it is whether the output is filtered with a capacitor or is it just a transformer and rectifier giving pulsating DC. I'm kind of suspecting that this is what's happening. You could test for this by adding a largish capacitor (100 to 1000 µF) across the motor and seeing what happens.

I added 20 mF capacitor to the adapter, the motor now can run but only without the razors attached to the motor (razors attached means the motor carrying load). Do I have to increase the capacity of the capacitor to get the motor run with razors attached? Do you think 20 mF is large enough or I am doing something wrong?

The motor most likely needs significantly more than 1000 mA or 1 ampere of current which your adapter is rated for, while the AA batteries are most likely capable of a higher current while maintaining sufficient voltage.
So, when you run it on batteries, it may be using about 2 amperes of current, and the voltage may be about 2+ volts under load.
But when you run it from the adapter, the supposed 3 volts drops down to maybe about 1+ volts, so the seemingly higher voltage supply turns into a lower voltage supply.
Additionally, the 4.2 volts you are seeing without a load is the internal voltage-smoothing capacitor charging up to the peak pulsed DC voltage (which comes after the AC is rectified or turned into DC):
the AC voltage of 3 volts is an effective 3 volts, but it changes from zero to maximum/peak positive voltage, swings back down to zero and continues to maximum/peak negative voltage, and then back up to zero towards positive peak, and this cycle repeats 50 or 60 times per second, depending on where you are in the world.
Below is the typical bridge rectifier which turns AC into pulsating DC.
Below it are the graphs for a 3Vac and 3Vdc.
As you can see, 3Vac is actually 4.23V peak, and that is the voltage to which the output smoothing capacitor charges when there is no load on the output.
But as soon as there is a load, the voltage drops to a lower DC value with some AC ripple in it.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab


